# Is the word "mucho" in "no te divertirás mucho" an adjective or an adverb? Why?

Tags: adjetivos, adverbios, categorías-gramaticales

I have been confused by the following phrase from a Spanish 3 class I am taking:

> no te divertirás mucho

The problem is the use of the word *mucho* in this sentence. I cannot understand whether it is supposed to be an adjective e.g. *You will not have much fun* or an adverb e.g. *You will not have fun much*.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

According to the RAE, the word *[mucho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PytaXRE)* can be an adjective if it goes along with a noun, a pronoun if it refers to a noun previously mentioned but omitted, or an adverb if it goes along with a verb. Some examples:

> *Esto es mucho trabajo para tan poco tiempo.* (Adjective, it modifies "trabajo".)
>
> *Trajeron un pan muy rico, pero no comimos mucho.* (Pronoun, it refers to "pan" but it is omitted.)
>
> *Llueve mucho y se va a desbordar el río.* (Adverb, it modifies "llueve".)

The problem with your sentence is the translation to English. In Spanish we have a verb ("divertirse") that translates to English as "to have fun", as if we said "tener diversión". So in the sentence "no te divertirás mucho", the word "mucho" modifies the verb, hence it is an adverb. But in "you won't have much fun", the word "much" modifies "fun" (a noun). If we said "tuvimos mucha diversión", then "mucha" would be an adjective as it would modify "diversión" (a noun).

Comment: Would it be easier to explain it if you translate the sentence to "You won't enjoy "(it) much"? I think it might help.

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out, it's useful to look carefully at the sentence in Spanish.  (Side benefit of this approach: once you understand what's modifying what, it will be easier to translate the sentence.)  Here's your original sentence again:

> No te divertirás mucho

For it to be an adverb, we should look for a verb that it modifies.  Candidate: "te diverterás".

for it to be an adjective, we should look for a noun that it modifies.  Problem: there aren't any nouns that that we can quantify as *much, many* or *few*.  The only noun here is the implied "you" ("tú").  It doesn't make any sense to modify a person with "mucho."

So, by elimination, "mucho" is modifying the verb.

A translation to English of the sentence that might help in your thinking about it might be

> You won't entertain yourself **a lot**.

where "a lot" is an adverb that modifies "entertain yourself."

(Sure, what this means in practice is "you won't have much fun," but a translation that mirrors the original syntax more closely can make it easier to understand how the sentence is put together.)